# Worksheetfunction in other sheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have copied and paste a code and it does not work properly. I have not changed anything and I am figuring out why it will not work. After a while i think I found the bug. I don't know how to fix it. This is the code

```
GroupPresence = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B1:D19"), salk)
```

it has to be something like this:

```
GroupPresence = WorksheetFunction.Worksheet("Sheet9").CountIf(Range("B1:D19"), salk)
```

The code is wrong? Does someone know what the correct code is in refering to another sheet.

Comment: The functions are global, the ranges belong to worksheets.

Answer (score 6):

Wrong syntax.  Use

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet9").Range("B1:D19"), Salk)
```

Comment: small typo in the answer above: it should be Worksheets("Sheet9") instead of Worksheet("Sheet9")